# Is there a way to connect my iPod touch to the internet without wireless connection (say, by usb)?

Tags: ipod-touch, internet

If I have no wireless connection, can I connect to the internet using the usb on the computer, or some other way?

Comment: You can teather an iPad to an iPhone over bluetooth.  You'd expect that you could tether an iPhone to a computer the same way--I'd like to be able to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not that I know of however you could try turning internet sharing on on your computer. This will create a wireless network that you can use on your iPod Touch.

This is easy to do if you are using a Mac. Assuming that internet comes in over Ethernet, go to the Sharing tab in the System Preferences application. Click the internet sharing tick box and configure it to share over Airport. (this is from memory as I don't have access to a Mac right at the moment but you can probably work it out.

Some further details are [available here](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=mac/10.5/en/8156.html).

Comment: Super nice ! I didn't know I could do that !!

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. It is like tethering but in reverse. :)

I don't think you have other options beside WiFi if you are not jailbroken. If you are, you could use [MyWi](http://intelliborn.com/mywi.html) to connect your iPod to an iPhone or iPad via Bluetooth. Costs $20 though.